# On EditText Changed Listener, Integer.parseInt() does not work

Tags: android, parsing, listener, onchange, android-edittext

when adding the line of parsing the text to integer the app stops, and it works well without this line

```
final TextView secNumber= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secNumber);
final EditText mainNumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mainNumber);

mainNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable S){
        secNumber.setText(Integer.parseInt(S.toString())*100);
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 secNumber.setText((Integer.parseInt(S.toString())*100).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out what's in `S`.  Apparently, it's not parseable.  Wrap the `parseInt` operation in a `try` `catch` block, or use a "TryParse", as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486082/102937).

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I didn't really expect it to parse `S`, since what is in `S` is already not parseable.

Comment: the application stops again when using a "TryParse", as illustrated above. there was no difference

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a Integer  for secNumber.setText( *Integer*) and the function probably needs a String. Put a toString() at end.

Try something like that

```
Integer  pipi= Integer.parseInt(S.toString())*100);
secNumber.setText(pipi.toString());
```