# Javascript regex for integer only, not to start with 0 but allow 0

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to validate integer numbers. `05 and 00` are not allowed but `0` is allowed.
Currently I have this:

```
/^[1-9]\d*$/
```

But it does not allow `0`. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 ^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)$
```

This is your pattern...

Comment: No reason to use capture grouping. Better one would be `^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)$`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I used parentheses to emphasize OR. Simply `^[1-9]\d*|0$` should do the trick.

Comment: No, you must not remove the parentheses, or you'll separate the regex into `(^[1-9]\d*)|(0$)`!

Comment: @AdamWolski - Wrong, that would match `12abc` or `xyz0`

Comment: @RafaelSedrakyan - `(?:   )` Non-capturing parentheses group the regex so you can apply regex operators, but do not capture anything and do not create backreferences.

Comment: @TimPietzcker thanks. it works for me on angular 6 FormGroup Validators.pattern the regex which you mentioned. (^[1-9]\d*)|(0$)!

Comment: @kva: My regex was an example of what not to do! The parentheses are crucial. If you use my regex, you match any string that starts with a non-zero digit or that ends in a 0, so it would match `1foo` or `bar0`.

Answer (score 7):

Your regex should be `^(?!0.)\d+$`