# Final variable might already have been assigned

Tags: java, variables, try-catch, final

I have a variable which must be `final` for a reason. But **while trying to assign a value to it, an `Exception` may be thrown** in such case I need it to be 0. So I tried something like this.

```
private static final int x;

static {
    try {
        x = (1 / 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        x = 0; //error line
    }
}
```

Surprisingly it gives me a compile-time error saying,

> variable `x` might already have been assigned.

I cannot understand this, `x` can only be assigned in `try` block OR in the `catch` block, possibly where else can a value be assigned to `x`? and how can I overcome this problem?

---

**EDIT :**

The best answer to this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13604193/2408342) by user [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/npe).

Comment: This is not a checked exception, but a compile time error. Since the `try`-block could be multi-lined and other lines after `x = (1 / 0);` could throw `Exception`s, the assignment in the `catch`-block could be a re-assignment, hence the compile time error.

Comment: @Turing85 I didn't see that, good point. Thanks.