# Why java doesn't support non-exceptional numbers parsing

Tags: java

What is the rationale behind not including such an essential method?

Probably a milion of people have implemented themselves code similar to the one below. Also many others have been forced to write their own number parsing if they couldn't afford exception catching (like importing a lot of data with huge parsing failure ratio).

Shouldn't that be enough reason to include it in the language?

```
    private Float tryParseFloat(String value) {
        try {
            return Float.parseFloat(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The only possible reason I can think of is that they don't want to make language a garbage. But I don't think adding such a method would.

Note:
I believe it's not a duplicate of [Java: Good way to encapsulate Integer.parseInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486077/java-good-way-to-encapsulate-integer-parseint) and similar as there is no discussion about the reasons why this method is missing.

Comment: You should probably be asking this at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ - StackOverflow isn't the place for this kind of question.

Comment: @HighCore Unfortunately lack of tryParse method is not enough of a reason to change my job.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Can I easly move my question there?

Comment: @Kuba if some moderator comes here he would be able to do that.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but oddly enough, [I can't find a JSR](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=parse) requesting that feature.