# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'XX' to data type int. in java eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'XX' to data type int. im having these error and i dont know what to do with it. please help me. THANKS. :D

```
   btnNewButton_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    String value1=textField_7.getText();
                     try{

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                         String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://;Database='';user='';password='';";
                         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
                       PreparedStatement pst =null;
                            //Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

       //PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from inventory where Id=? or Name=? ");
                        String sql ="select * from inventory where Id=? or Name=? ";
                        pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                        pst.setString(1, textField_7.getText());
                        pst.setString(2, textField_7.getText());


                     ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                     if(value1.equals("")){
                          reloadData();
                          model.fireTableDataChanged();
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter a Name or Id of the Item","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                      }else{  


                                  table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                  }

                           }


                     catch(Exception e1){e1.printStackTrace();}

                }


            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the SQL Statement from

```
select * from inventory where Id=? or Name=?
```

to

```
select * from inventory where CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(50))=? or Name=?
```

The problem is that you are using the same text field to compare to both `Id` and `Name`, so if you were to enter *Rohan* into the text field it would try to convert it to an `INT` to compare to `Id`, in which case the statement would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Id Column is integral, you're getting this error because you are trying to assign it a string. If the [field is integral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486077/java-good-way-to-encapsulate-integer-parseint/1486082#1486082), parse the textField to an int and then use [`setInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

```
pst.setInt(1, parsedInt);
```