# JSP, Integer.parseInt throw error even when testing for null

Tags: java, jsp

here is the code

```
if(var!=null) {
                        int varInt= Integer.parseInt(var);
                        method.setProp(varInt);
              }
```

After some reseach it normally throw error when we're not testing for null, but I am, so what's the problem?

**The Error**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /TravelSearch.jsp at line 81               
80:                    if(var!=null) {
81:                         int varInt= Integer.parseInt(var);
82:                         method.setProp(varInt);
83:                     }
84:                     
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:567)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
cause mère
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Comment: Whats the exception? A `null` check will not prevent invalid values in `var` that can't be parsed to an integer

Comment: var may contain a special character(space,...)

Comment: I'm testing the var without any input

Comment: `""` do you think it can be parsed to a Number ?

Comment: but the i'm puting nothing in the  field so i'm supposed to test for null not ""

Comment: testing for null is not enough you have to check it if it has a valid int chracter  becaue `""` is not int

Comment: That's the exact thing you're told in the exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
What number is empty string? - what you want is a method equivalent to Int.TryParse() in C#.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The number you're trying to parse isn't null, it's an empty string `""`.  The stacktrace was telling you this here:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Change your test to do this:

```
if(var!=null && !"".equals(var)) {
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, this one work for me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer by Jon Skeet.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486082/891261

This is what you want - a method that checks if the string can be parsed to a number and returns an obvious illegal value when it does not, which you then can check for and act on.