# Is exception handling in this manner acceptable?

Tags: java, exception

Let's say I have a piece of code that takes user input and stores it in integer. Now when user enters something else, the `NumberFormat` exception is thrown. But since I know this may happen, but there is no reason for me to do anything about it besides checking it and then re-run the input sequence, would it be terrible idea to put the `try-catch` inside `do-while` loop and making a boolean a control variable? Is there a case where such exception handling could backfire at me?

Pseudo-code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean inputMismatch;
int number;
do {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        inputMismatch = false;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        inputMismatch = true;
    }

} while (inputMismatch);
```

Comment: No, that's a pretty common use case (for such applications).

Comment: Yup. Looks like a sound methodology to me.

Comment: If there's an easy way to check without cathcing an exception, use it (e.g. calling `file.exists()` to avoid `FileNotFoundExdception`). In your case however, there's no such way, so catching the exception is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: I would rather use `hasNextInt` and `next`/`nextLine` in case of an invalid input instead of catching an exception, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's fine, but a little bit clumsy with the extra variable. I would do something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int number;
while(true) {
  try {
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    break;
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Now the control will break out of the while loop if the integer parses successfully, otherwise will print the error. Consider printing the message rather than the stack trace - users get confused by stack traces.

Comment: +1 for not printing the stacktrace. i'd go further and say, because the exception is handled, there likely isn't any need to print in the catch.

Answer (score 3):

If you weren't going to include the `catch` in this block of code, it'd have to be one level up - namely, something would have to do this same loop and catch the exception.  The only difference would be that it's encapsulated in a method which would throw the runtime exception.

This should be perfectly fine to do.  You have to deal with the invalid input *somewhere*, and here looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic and coding both look fine. This code will do exactly what you want with a minimum of side effects.  You can also use a `for` or `while` loop to avoid having an uninitialized flag in the beginning. In the case of for loop, the flag will not even exist outside the loop:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int number;
for(boolean inputMismatch = true; inputMismatch; ) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        inputMismatch = false;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that you do not have to reset `inputMismatch` to `true` for every failed iteration of the loop if you do it before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

**I think that's absolutely fine.**

You could potentially encapsulate the parsing logic somewhere else so that the error handling is perhaps a little more explicit.

Here's a reference about the encapsulation:

[Java: Good way to encapsulate Integer.parseInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486077/java-good-way-to-encapsulate-integer-parseint)