# How can I parse String to int with the default value?

Tags: java, string, integer, default-value, parseint

I need to parse a string user id into integer for that I used `Integer.parseInt(String s)` but it returns null/nil, if there string has/holds non-decimal/integer value and in that case, I need to assign default integer value as `0`.

I tried this but it `(? 0)` seems not working and I don't know whether it is correct syntax or not.

```
String userid = "user001";
int int_userid = Integer.parseInt(userid) ? 0;
```

How can assign default value to integer if there is null assignment?

String userid is a parameter argument as part of web service function call, so I cannot update it's data type to integer.

Comment: You have invented a syntax that does not exist in Java. `parseInt` throws an exception if it can't parse the string. You can `catch` the exception to deal with that case.

Comment: "but it returns null, if there string has non-integer value" No it doesn't. An int-returning method can't return null. It throws an exception.

Comment: When you would run the program you should see an exception in eclipse console.

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1486521/1898563

Comment: Is there any way to handle this situation/issue?

Comment: @Michael thanks dear, let me try it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're most likely using apache.commons.lang3 already:

```
NumberUtils.toInt(str, 0);
```

Answer (score 11):

That syntax won't work for `Integer.parseInt()`, because it will result in a [`NumberFormatException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39850130/4723795)

You could handle it like this:

```
String userid = "user001";
int int_userid;
try {
   int_userid = Integer.parseInt(userid);
} catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
   int_userid = 0;
}
```

*Please note that your variable names **do not conform with the Java Code Convention***

---

A better solution would be to create an **own method** for this, because I'm sure that **you will need it more than once**:

```
public static int parseToInt(String stringToParse, int defaultValue) {
    try {
       return Integer.parseInt(stringToParse);
    } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
       return defaultValue; //Use default value if parsing failed
    }
}
```

Then you simply use this method like for e.g.:

```
int myParsedInt = parseToInt("user001", 0);
```

This call returns the default value `0`, because "user001" can't be parsed.

If you remove "user" from the string and call the method...

```
int myParsedInt = parseToInt("001", 0);
```

…then the parse will be successful and return `1` since an int can't have leading zeros!

Comment: Where did you invent `p_ex` from??

Comment: Just a variable name nothing to invent here

Comment: That's just a variable for the NumberFormatException. You could use it like `p_ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: I know. The question is what caused, that you called Java variable this way?

Comment: Ah I see. I use "p_" to declare a variable as parameter

Answer (score 7):

It might be a little over-engineering, but you can use Guava's `Ints.tryParse(String)` with Java 8's Optionals like this:

```
int userId = Optional.ofNullable(Ints.tryParse("userid001")).orElse(0)
```

Comment: This introduces extra boxing and unboxing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this way with `String::matches` like this :

```
String userid = "user001";
int int_userid = userid.matches("\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(userid) : 0;
```

You ca also use `-?\d+` for both positive and negative values :

```
int int_userid = userid.matches("-?\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(userid) : 0;
```

Comment: Wasn't my downvote and I'm not a regex guru but it seems a roundabout way and wouldn't it fail for negative numbers?

Comment: @PeterJ what about now ? :)

Comment: @YCF_L perfect over-engineering :D

Comment: You nailed it. Excellent

Comment: I have a feeling that "Not a real answer" was prepared for this kind of answers :p

Comment: @YCF_L looks better but wouldn't it need bounds checking as well to make sure it can be mapped to an int?

Comment: yes @PeterJ correct, in my solution i use regex and the range of the int is between `-2147483648` and `2147483647` so this can be work but with a big pattern, i will go with the solution of (Yannick or xenteros) instead using try catch is the better way in this case ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this method with a regular expression.

```
public static int parseWithDefault(String s, int defaultVal) {
    return s.matches("-?\\d+") ? Integer.parseInt(s) : defaultVal;   
}
```

Comment: It won't work if the value exceeds the range of an int.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can achieve what you want by the following method:

```
public static int parseIntWithDefault(String s, int default) {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return default;
    }
}
```

and now just assign:

```
int int_userid = parseIntWithDefault(userId, 0);
```

Please have in mind, that using `Java` one should use Java good practices about formatting the code. `int_userid` is definitely something to improve.

Comment: Quick Question, usually using try/catch to handle logic flow is an antipattern. I guess in this scenario this is the only option, right? 

Is verifying that s is not null and is created only using digits, points or that kind of verification better ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String userid = "user001";
int int_userid = Integer.parseInt(userid) != null ? Integer.parseInt(userid) : 0);
```

Did you mean this syntax?
But since an `int` can never be `null` you have to instead do:

```
String userid = "user001";
int int_userid;
try { 
    int_userid= Integer.parseInt(userid);
} catch (NumberFormatexception e) {
    int_userid = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int int_userid;
try {
    int_userid = Integer.parseInt(userid); // try to parse the given user id
} catch (Exception e) {   // catch if any exception
    int_userid = 0; // if exception assign a default value
}
```

Comment: Look, it's one of the answers, but the only one with not even a word to explain...

Comment: But that shouldn't be the reason for down vote, anyways I would keep that in mind.

Comment: [Answers with explanations](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) are more useful for future visitors, and more likely to get upvoted. Comment votes don't count for reputation, so they're often used to indicate agreement. If you feel a comment is "too chatty" and ought to be deleted, you can always flag it for moderator attention.